# Rails 7 link/group struct objects with the same ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 and Ruby 3.2.1 application I'm fetching consolidations/deconsolidations data from an external API via below method:

```
    def fetch_consolidations(strong_params)
      client
        .consolidations_index(strong_params)
        .concat(client.deconsolidations_index(strong_params))
    end
```

Both consolidation and deconsolidation are objects from Dry::Struct gem:

```
module FileProcessing
  class Deconsolidation < ::Core::ApplicationEntity
    attribute :id, Types::String
    attribute :consolidation_id, Types::String.optional.default(nil)

    # other attributes (...)

  end
end

module DtfsFileProcessing
  class Consolidation < ::Core::ApplicationEntity
    attribute :id, Types::String

    # other attributes (...)

  end
end
```

Now I want to group/link deconsolidation with consolidation in my table view. It means `fetch_consolidations` should return an array of objects grouped to match deconsolidation and consolidation. Be aware that `deconsolidation.consolidation_id == consolidation.id` so the end result should be:

```
[#<DtfsFileProcessing::Deconsolidation consolidation_id="33" (...),
 <DtfsFileProcessing::Deconsolidation consolidation_id="33" (...),
#<DtfsFileProcessing::Consolidation id="33" (...),
#<DtfsFileProcessing::Deconsolidation consolidation_id="777" (...),
#<DtfsFileProcessing::Deconsolidation consolidation_id="777" (...),
#<DtfsFileProcessing::Consolidation id="777"]
```

Comment: I am not sure I see a grouping there (looks more like sorting) but if you already have that array `arr.group_by {|e| e.is_a?(DtfsFileProcessing::Deconsolidation) ? e.consolidation_id : e.id}` will result in a `Hash` of `{id => [grouping]}` you could take this a step further with and `each_with_object` loop to group them as `{id => {consolidations => [], deconsolidations => []}}`. There are likely other suitable ways to organize this data as well but I am not 100% certain I understand the specific desired outcome.